# Entity Framework Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

Have a scenario with a client's new crm where they have suppliers and clients and a supplier is also a client and vice versa. Table per hierarchy will only allow a person to only be one or the other, so I assume table per type would be better suited.

The db structure would be:

```
[Contact]
ContactId pk
Name
...

[Client]
ContactId pk / fk
VATNumber
...

[Supplier]
ContactId pk / fk
...
```

Anyone have any other suggestions or experience from a similar scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table per type will also assume one `Contact` is either a client or a supplier (this is clearer if you look at the generated SQL: eg. see ["Inheritance with EF Code First CTP5: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)"](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)).

Instead I think you need to change your model to be `Contact` and `Contact-Role` with a one to many relationship. `Contact-Role` would have the `Supplier` and `Client` subtypes. The whole `Contact-Role` hierarchy could then be mapped as TPH or TPT.

This reflects an OO design where each client has one or more roles (inheritance, "is-a" releationship, will always be singular, you cannot have an object of abstract type `client` that is simultaneously both subtypes of `client`).

Comment: Thanks Richard, This is interesting, could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work unless you model it as three level inheritance which would require that either client is always supplier or supplier is always client. I guess that is not correct model in your application which means you cannot use inheritance.

You have to either use one-to-one (0..1-1) relations between contact-client and contact-supplier or you can simply place all properties to single table and add `IsClient` and `IsSupplier` bit columns - it is not very nice and it is less extensible but it is very easy to use. These two bit columns can be useful in case of relational representation as well.